# Best to way execute a file internal to a java project

Tags: java

Suppose my project structure is:

```
/project
  /src
    /java
      Util.java
    /cpp
  /bin
    a.out
```

I'd like to execute a.out from within Util.java without hard-coding any absolute paths in my java file. What's the best way to go about doing this?

EDIT -- Here's what I ended up doing: I happen to be using autoconf as most of the code is c++.  I defined a substitution variable like `AC_SUBST([project_root], [$(pwd)])` in configure.ac and substituted it in a Config.java.in file.

Comment: Are you deploying the project as a JAR?

Comment: Actually, I may want to deploy as a JAR in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using a *properties* file to be loaded on deployment/running time depending on the nature of your app.

More about its use in this thread
[How to use Java property files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Comment: Don't I still need to store an absolute path in the property file?

Comment: Perhaps you can get the context path when your app starts, so you add the relative route from the properties. The absolute path is also an option

Answer (score 0):

You're file path to `a.out` could be `../bin/a.out`. And then execute the file using that path.

Answer (score -1):

Below is some pseudo code that might help you.

```
// look for the executable in the current working directory 
File executable = new File("a.out");
if( executable.exists()){
   System.exec() .... etc
} else {
   String location = YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
   // write code to form a path name to the a.out based on the location of .jar file 
}
```