# Best way to invoke remote EJB

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I am trying to improve my understanding of remote EJB invocation.

I have code like this working, which does a remote JNDI lookup on my server:

```
private InitialContext jndiContext;    
private AdderBeanRemote bean1;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "10.0.0.99");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
jndiContext = new InitialContext(props);
bean1 = (AdderBeanRemote) jndiContext.lookup("com.suspectclass.sgifford.test8bean.AdderBeanRemote");
```

But that seems way to complicated, and hardcodes a lot of application-specific data into my application; for example, if I wanted to use a different server or renumber my network, I would have to modify my application then recompile and redeploy.

I have seen some solutions that use "jndi.properties", but so far I haven't gotten any to work, and at any rate this would still require me to recompile and redeploy to change anything.

Is there a simpler way of doing this that doesn't require hardcoding my network details into my app?  Or is this the best I can do?

Thanks!

-----Scott.

Answer (score 0):

I think an external .properties file is the way to go to avoid recompilation.

This file could either be outside the packaged .jar as a separate file in the filesystem

or packaged into a "configuration-resources.jar" that you bring onto the classpath. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files) question covers the basic of reading properties on some different deployment scenarios

If you want to dwelve more into the jndi.properties, read more at [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html), i guess using jndi.properties is more of the recommended way, as you avoid reading properties programatically. But you might reach faster results by just reading a home-made .properties-file from the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to learn more about the configuration-resources.jar!

Comment: I might have mislead you. What i meant was, you could package configuration files into a separate .jar instead of bundling them in your application jar. There is no concept here, its just a name i made up.

Comment: Ah, I see, I googled "configuration-resources.jar" and came up with some hits, so I thought it was a thing.  So they would just be a separate JAR inside my application WAR or EAR file?