# What is the difference between System.getProperty and properties.getProperty in Java

Tags: java

I have a properties file, named `prop.properties`. In my main code, I have both `System.getProperty()` and `properties.getProperty()`.

My question is: are they both get property from `prop.properties` or they will get property from different places, `properties.getProperty()` get property from `prop.properties` and `System.getProperty()` get property from other place.

Comment: Depends on where `properties` came from.  If `Properties properties = System.getProperties();`, then yes, they will be the same.  If `Properties propertes = new Properties();`, then no, they won't be.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`System.getProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) gets a property as defined by the JVM (either the JVM itself or any `-D` options you may have passed at the command line). The list of defined properties can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) (thanks @NikitaBeloglazov).

`properties.getProperty()` is the result of someone having initialized an object of type [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). They are not the same, though [you can get what `System` has as a `Properties` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).

A `Properties` object is very often the result of loading a Java property file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files) for how this is done)

Comment: Can you add link to java tutorial about system properties? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Answer (score 15):

`System.getProperty(propName)` is a shortcut for `System.getProperties().getProperty(propName)`.

However `java.util.Properties` is just a subclass of `java.utils.Hashtable`, so its instance may be created everywhere in code and populated with any data. Obviously code

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.getProperty("os.name");
```

is the same as

```
System.getProperty("os.name");
```

However

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("myprops.properties"))
props.getProperty("os.name");
```

is not the same.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now i can figure out.

Answer (score 4):

The `System` class refers to the JVM you are running (which would get info from your OS). When you use `getProperty` on `System` you get actual properties.

The `Property` class is basically a glorified hash table. You can completely define it yourself, so when you do `getProperty()` you get the results that you set up. The usefulness of the `Property` class is that it has a built in XML parser so you can read in properties from a file.