# Spring Boot HTML Location

Tags: spring-boot

New to spring boot and just wondering how does it find the Html files within the project. Is the a dependency I need or is it automatically configured when spring boot is added the maven project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to service external static HTML files in Spring Boot Embedded tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064241/how-to-service-external-static-html-files-in-spring-boot-embedded-tomcat)

Answer (score 2):

The default spring-boot path to static files is a folder named *static* saved in *src/main/resources*. See the spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content) and [example](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

Answer (score 1):

For static resources, the default path is /static;/public;/resources;/META-INF/resources.

If you want to change it, change this

> spring.resources.static-locations=