# vue path for index.js is wrong

Tags: java, spring, vue.js

I just study vue.js and my problem is:
if I open index.html then index.js open too, but if I start srping boot, my index.html works correct and doesn't see index.js.
[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULNoG.png)

```
<body>
    <div id="armors"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Every time you open the *index.html* file with your browser, a new window opens in your browser which shows the content of your *index.js* file ?

Comment: if i open only index.html file, without spring boot, vue components inject from index.js to index.html. it's ok. but with deploy application in spring boot it doesn't work. i get an error like GET http://localhost:8080/js/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404. it's somthing about path problems, but i move index.js in different place and it doesn't work

Comment: I haven't really worked on spring, but I believe static assets(like js files) should be moved to a static directory. Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925712/spring-boot-add-html-and-javascript)