# Could not autowire - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot

I am trying to build a restful web service with Spring Boot, Maven, and Tomcat.

When I try to deploy maven jar file to Tomcat I receive this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'selectConfRoomController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate hello.SelectConfRoomController.jt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate hello.SelectConfRoomController.jt; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

My application.properties file is in package src/main/resources

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://***
spring.datasource.username=***
spring.datasource.password=***
spring.datasource.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

src/main/java

Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Querying...

```
package hello;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController 
public class SelectConfRoomController extends JdbcTemplate{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jt;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Region> getRegions(){

        String sql = "SELECT OUID_Region, RegionName FROM Region";
        List <Region> rows = jt.query(sql, 
                new RowMapper<Region>(){
            @Override
            public Region mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                return new Region(rs.getLong("OUID_Region"), rs.getString("RegionName"));
            }
        });

        System.out.println("querying regions");
        return rows; 
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice-test</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
      <finalName>ConfRoom</finalName>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Reading the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044292/spring-boot-how-to-externalize-jdbc-datasource-configuration), I'm under the impression that I would not need an xml file. Can someone find an error that I'm not aware of? I am very new to all this so any expertise/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you declare the `JdbcTemplate` bean that you're trying to autowire a reference to?  If you're not declaring that bean, then that's why it's not able to autowire it in...

Comment: It's a Spring Boot application - you don't need to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the problem is, that you extend the JdbcTemplate. Spring Boot only creates a JdbcTemplate, if no other bean with this type is found. But your class is a bean of type JdbcTemplate, so the autoconfiguration for the JdbcTemplate is skipped. Try to remove the "extends JdbcTemplate", it doesn't seem to be required for your class.

Comment: You're right! I got a different error message after I removed "extends JdbcTemplate" but I worked through that and now it works. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the JDBCTemplate in context xml like below or you need to add the package for component scan.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

```
 <bean id="jtDataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="*******"/>
    <property name="url" value="*******"/>
    <property name="username" value="*****"/>
    <property name="password" value="**********"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jtDataSource"/> --Incase if you are configuring data source
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a bean with `JdbcTemplate`

```
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource(){
    /* Return the data source with proper configuration... */
}


@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;



@Bean
public JdcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    return dataSource;
}
```