# Placing a properties file in a java project

Tags: java

I am having some trouble understanding where to place a properties file in a java project. 
I have the following project structure .

```
src.
   |
    java
        |
         test.properties
                        |
                        a.java
                        Parameters.properties
```

I have the following code to read the properties file .

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();


    try {
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Parameters.properties");
       // load a properties file
        prop.load(in);
       // get the property value and print it out
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("hello.world"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("The code has failed here");
    }
```

my properties file has the following line

```
hello.world=Hello World
```

I keep getting a null pointer error which leads me to believe it is not able to read the file because it has not got the file yet .

Comment: it may be helpful to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Comment: Does your properties files exist in your compiled classes folder?

Comment: ^ I tried that but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your file `Parameters.properties` not in `src` folder, but in `built` or `target` folder. Or for simple explanation find `a.class` file and put `Parameters.properties` in the same folder.

```
built.
   |
    java
        |
         test.properties
                        |
                        a.class
                        Parameters.properties
```

Because when you use `getClass()` method you get binary file with `.class` extension and search resources in folder where this file is.

Answer (score 0):

1.) One way of doing this is ---
**Add your properties file in any source folder.**
A source folder is a folder that is included in class path.
e.g. src/ A.java
Create another Source folder

at src level
and place file here

resources/params.properties.

And in A.java acces like this `File file = new File(".//resources//params.properties");`

2.) Another easy way Add properties file in src folder, and  Right click on properties file -> build Path ->Add to Class Path.

And Access file in A.java like this....

```
File file = new File("params.properties");
```

Comment: Its Add to build Path or class path can't recall !!