# How to invoke a java-method which name is set in a .properties file

Tags: java

I would like to make an indirect call to a java method, which name is specified in a `.properties` file.

How can I do that ?

Comment: You could use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: look at this link good example for .properties file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files

Comment: Lets be clear here.  You want to get the name of the method you are going to call from the properties file.  This way any method might be invoked depending on how the properties file is configured.  Right?

Comment: Do you know the name of the **class** on which you want to call this **method** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object object = // .....
try(is = propertiesInputStream()) {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(is);
    Method m = org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(object.getClass(), p.get("method"));
    Object result = org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(m, object);
}
```

Comment: `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod`? What's the dependency on that one?

Comment: `spring-core 4.1.5.RELEASE`, and other versions

Comment: I believe, you don´t need Spring for this, the JDK provides you with an API to do reflection and invoke methods (even if they are private). Let me look for it...

Comment: See [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/160976/3046834)

Comment: I agree, you don't need Spring. Spring is just a convenience.