# assging name to the variable depending on the function parameter

Tags: java, variables

I am creating a function in my java class such as assignval(int i). in  this function i need to create the dynamic variable such when int value is 1 .I should have

```
String []data_value1 =data1.split(",");

String []key_value1 =key1.split(",");
which i am reading from property file.
when int value is 2 
String []data_value2 =data2.split(",");

String []key_value1 =key1.split(",");
```

so on

how can i achieve this.

i tried the below code but it dint work:

```
String assignval(int i){

Sting [] data_val+" "+i=DATA+" "+i.split(,)

String[] key_values+" "+i = key+" "+i.split(",");

}
```

where DATA i am reading from a property file.

```
property file:
DATA1=abc,def,ghi

DATA2=jkl,mno,pqr

key1=name,date

key2=place,address
so on 
thanks in advance.
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Java property files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Comment: Can you give some examples with expected output and so on. I don't understand your question as well.