# How can read properties file from outside of folder If i declare the properties file as config.properties

Tags: java

I created the properties file, say `config.properties`. Now I would like to know the procedure about how to read the parameter value from properties file in `java`.

Using jdk1.7 in eclipse.

Comment: [http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0220__I18N/AnInternationalizedSwingApplication.htm] look at this URL

Comment: Please check [here](http://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/). Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Comment: Notepad has diddly-squat to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

See the below code for reading config.properties file. Property file can be any where in the file system. You have to give the correct absolute path to the properties file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

class ConfigReader
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream inputstream;
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            inputstream = new FileInputStream("pathtofile\\config.properties");
            if(inputstream!=null)
            {
                prop.load(inputstream);
                String property1 = prop.getProperty("property1");
                String property2 = prop.getProperty("property2");
                System.out.println(property1+"\n"+property2);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("File not found");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: properties are most often placed somewhere on the classpath, so you can use MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);