# JAVA questions regarding super() keyword and .properties file from GRAL installation

Tags: java, properties, runtime, super

As a JAVA beginner, I tried using [GRAL](http://trac.erichseifert.de/gral/) via a tutorial. I came about the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Property file not found: drawablewriters.properties
```

This runtime error came from the following lines of unaltered GRAL source code:

```
public final class DrawableWriterFactory extends AbstractIOFactory<DrawableWriter> {
 /** Singleton instance. */
 private static DrawableWriterFactory instance;

 /**
  * Constructor that initializes the factory.
  * @throws IOException if the properties file could not be found.
  */
 private DrawableWriterFactory() throws IOException {
  super("drawablewriters.properties"); //$NON-NLS-1$
 }

 /**
  * Returns an instance of this DrawableWriterFactory.
  * @return Instance.
  */
 public static DrawableWriterFactory getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
   try {
    instance = new DrawableWriterFactory();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
  }
  return instance;
}
```

The class above is reference in another class which is referenced the code that was initially run.

After reading about the keyword [super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), it seems super would never have a .properties file as an argument when used in a constructor. How does it use a .properties file in this case?

I noticed in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files?rq=1) that a new InputStream is typically used to extract the contents of a .properties file. Is this somehow done with super?

Also, I simply tried placing drawablewriters.properties in the same directory as the source code above. This didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `super("drawablewriters.properties");` is merely an invocation of the constructor of this class' superclass.  It can have whatever arguments are taken by one of the superclass' constructors.  In this case it is invoking a constructor of `AbstractIOFactory<DrawableWriter>`.

The problem in your case is that the file `drawablewriters.properties` is not where the superclass constructor can find it.  You should look at the documentation for `AbstractIOFactory` to learn how it resolves properties file names.