# Using a property field value within ' ' in java?

Tags: java, properties-file

I have a property file in my project, say config.properties, having a property field `project.searchkey`. Can I have the value of this field as `project.searchkey = 'one','two'`?

Will it be considering both the values **with the '' sign**?

Comment: That depends on the software that's reading and using the properties file, and since we don't know what software that is, we cannot tell you.

Comment: Depends how you will work with that file, if you will use common [`Properties` and `FileInputStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1318391/4892907) then it should not matter...
Btw isnt it faster simply try, then ask? :)

Comment: why don't you just try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `java.util.Properties` ([see API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html))

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
            String propertyValue = prop.getProperty("project.searchkey");
            System.out.println(propertyValue);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints `'one','two'`, so it reads everything after the `=` **as a single String**

`project.searchkey='one','two'` returns `'one','two'`

`project.searchkey=one,two` returns `one,two`

`project.searchkey=one, 'two'` returns `one, 'two'`

etc ...

Answer (score 1):

```
project.searchkey=one, two, \
                  three, four, \
                  five
```

Best not to have keys with commas, and hence not needing single quotes.
After retrieval of the String value for key `"project.searchkey"`:

```
String value = bundle.getProperty("project.searchkey");
// value is "one, two, three, four, five"
String[] searchKeys = value.split(",\\s*"); // Split by comma and any whitespace.
```

Of course single quotes could be removed for value.