# Where to store environment specific configuration

Tags: java

I have a project which currently runs locally.

I have all my configuration **hard-coded** in a class. (DB IP, DB Username, DB Password, FTP IP, FTP Username, FTP Password)

This makes it very difficult to deploy the project on Local/Test/Production Environments unless they use the same IP, UserName, Passwords.

I want to be able to share the project and not share any credentials.

Where and how do I store these credentials?

I currently use **Gradle** for building the project.

Deployment is done using **Jenkins**

The project is shared on **GitHub**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Java property files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Comment: Various options. 1. Read from an external property file which exists in each environment. Set JVM properties. 2. Pass as JVM args: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-set-system-properties.html?page=2

Comment: are you using spring framework?

Answer (score -3):

Start by evaluating your application and comparing it against https://12factor.net especially https://12factor.net/config

Typically you would want to externalise your configurations into some files (`*.properties` or `*.yaml`). Each files represent an environment (dev, test, prod).

Lastly, make sure your Gradle project should only produce 1 generic artefact.

Comment: Hmm. My answer gets the asker in the right direction. Also, a down vote reason would be appreciated.