# How to create .properties file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am going to use a .properties file for a project I am working on.  However, I am not able to find a way to do this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a new file called `whatever.properties`. They're text files. What's the specific issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Java property files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318347/how-to-use-java-property-files)

Comment: Just drag a file with the name you want into your project, or create a new text file within the IDE and give it the name you want.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click in the project panel to select **New File**

[image]

or click the **New File icon** behind the project bar

[image]

and create a file with a suffix of `.properties`.

[image]